# publishing calibration data with bag file

Tags: ros, rosbag, camera, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I recorded a bag file with a video sequence. The corresponding bag file does only contain the image_raw topic, as by the time I recorded the sequence I had not calibrated the camera yet.

Now I have calibrated the camera, and I would like to play the bag file and simultaneously publish the camera_info data so that, for example, I can undistort the images from the bag file using image_proc.

How can I start a publisher that only publishes the camera_info ? Or could I add this camera_info in some way to the pre-existing bag file ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61008/publishing-calibration-data-with-bag-file/) by [BeLioN](https://answers.ros.org/users/2449/belion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2013-04-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liyun](https://answers.ros.org/users/57810/liyun/) on 2020-08-14**:
Hello!
Have you complemented this function? I'm also meeting this problem.
If you have solved this, may I please get your some reference?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi BeLioN,

please take a look at our [image_sequence_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/bag_tools?distro=fuerte#image_sequence_publisher.py) where we publish images as a ros topic, while we read a yaml file and publish it as calibration for a "fake" camera.

You could take part of our code to make a node that publishes your calibration info in the correct topic.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's always the option of manually running a publisher using the `rostopic` command line tool while replaying the bag file, but I think this will probably turn out to be too cumbersome.

Adding the CameraInfo messages to the bag file is probably a more convenient solution. You can add them to the existing bag quite easily by using the rosbag API. The examples in the [rosbag Cookbook](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Cookbook) will probably help you find out how.

---

Originally posted by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) with karma: 1071 on 2013-04-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2